# I want to set my spinner in this layout with dropdown triangle icon

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is my spinner layout and I'm setting the spinner inside the table layout in second row. I'm wrapping the spinner and giving manually height and width to it. When i set its weight and height to wrap content it's layout make a issues.

so i want to set the spinner in this layout with drop-down arrow also.

```
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/list_divider"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Lot Qty."
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Lot Size"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Unit Price"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/lot_qty_spinner"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"

                android:popupBackground="#DFFFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/size"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:text="size"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/unit_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: it will be helpfull if you provide image as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove background color from background.

Remove android:background="#ffffff"

Try with this.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/details"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/list_divider"
android:stretchColumns="*" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Lot Qty."
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Lot Size"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Unit Price"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/lot_qty_spinner"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:popupBackground="#DFFFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/size"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="size"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unit_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```